# getting the index of set bits from an int column in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

Anyone have any SQL-fu (can be MySQL-specific) that will give me the indexes of set bits in an int, without using a procedure?  How about with a procedure?

For example, given:

```
create table example (val int);
insert into example values (1), (2), (3), (4), (256);
```

I can see the set bits:

```
select conv(val, 10, 2) from example;
+------------------+
| conv(val, 10, 2) |
+------------------+
| 1                | 
| 10               | 
| 11               | 
| 100              |
| 100000000        | 
+------------------+
```

I need magic that will give me:

```
+------------------+
| (something)      |
+------------------+
| 1                | 
| 2                | 
| 1,2              | 
| 3                | 
| 9                | 
+------------------+
```

.. happy to get 0-based, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MySQL function [MAKE_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_make-set) does this:

```
SELECT
    MAKE_SET( val, '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' )
FROM
    example
```

There's probably some other function that will generate the series of number strings too ... anyone?

Comment: You know, I was looking at MySQL sets and wishing the implementation wasn't confined to table structures.  Thanks for this, exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a starter maybe... At least in T-SQL there is a bit wise operator you can use to combine values with what ever input value. Basically the rule is 
if 
input & bitvalue = bitvalue 
then the bit is turned on.

```
declare @i int
set @i =40
select @i & 1, @i & 2, @i & 4, @i & 8, @i & 16, @i & 32, 
       @i & 64, @i & 128, @i & 256
```

Comment: +1 So does MySQL http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-and

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM CONCAT(IF(x&1, "1,", ""), 
                                     IF(x&2, "2,", ""),
                                     IF(x&4, "3,", ""), ...))
```